# Animagus Event- is it still available?

Tags: harry-potter-hogwarts-mystery

Okay, so in an update on Hogwarts Mystery, there was this Animagus Event that I obviously missed.

Anyways, according to what I read, the Event is available for Years 3 and above. I'm still at Year 2, so of course I didn't get the notification.

Now my question, is it still available? As in, I could get the side quest upon reaching Year 3?

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, I can confirm that these Special Events can be completed after their release window -- or at least some of them can, including the Animagus event.

I spent several months away from the game in the middle of Year Four, and when I returned, the game unlocked several events in a row, including many that belonged to earlier years. I only ever had one active at a time, but after each one ended, another would begin within the same day. The impression I got was that the game had effectively "queued up" events that I should have triggered by that point (say, by having passed a certain chapter in-story). I also triggered a Year Four event (to become a Prefect) in the course of my normal play, which seemed to take priority over the backlog, as it came between the Frog Choir and Weird Sisters events for me.

I can't confirm that *every* event can be completed after the fact in this way, as there are still events I haven't seen. Some may require an element of real-world timing, for example, such as the Christmas event.

I looked for any sort of official source (update notes, perhaps) to corroborate my experience, but I haven't found anything.